# accidentally opened up a line of credit - what can i do?

Tags: united-states, credit-card, credit-score, credit

So I was trying to update my address on my PayPal Credit Card and apparently I opened up a new line of PayPal Credit instead. Like apparently the PayPal Credit Card and PayPal Credit are two completely different products.

I cancelled it immediately but I'm concerned that this might negatively impact my credit score. The fact that I cancelled it immediately should mean that my average account age and the number of open accounts should be unaffected but, at minimum, it means I most likely have a new hard credit pull, which, itself, dings my credit.

My question is...  what are my options?

Comment: Are you about to take out a major new loan, or undergo background check for an apartment, or do something 
 else where your exact credit rating might actually matter? If not, don't sweat the small stuff.

Answer (score 1):

If you have applied for credit, then it will appear on your credit record as an application for credit.  That may lower your score in the short term.

The best thing to do is absolutely nothing.  Your credit score will gradually return to normal.